# Teradata: tdload error

Tags: teradata

I get the following error for the following command:

```
tdload -f ./file.csv -t t1 -u u1 -p -d ',' --TargetWorkingDatabase db1 -h host1
```

file.csv is quite small (around 50k lines).

Error:

```
Teradata Load Utility Version 14.00.00.08

Password: **********
Teradata Parallel Transporter Version 14.00.00.08
TPT_INFRA: TPT04039: Error: TPT Job script source 'Generated SQL INSERT Stmt for DBS Table 'D_TBL001'' is empty.

Job script preprocessing failed.
Job terminated with status 8.
```

How do I go about debugging/fixing this?

Comment: The table name you specify with the -t parameter does not match the table in the error message. Not sure if you copied something incorrectly or not.

Comment: I substituted the name of the table in the tdload command.  The error message is copied verbatim.  But the table name I actually used in the tdload command was not 'D_TBL001' (i.e. it was neither t1 nor D_TBL001).